# Why is r.grow.distance in GRASS GIS returning a raster with all values = 0?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, distance, euclidean

I'm trying to create a raster map that contains "Euclidean" distances to roads from another raster that contains said roads, by using r.grow.distance in GRASS GIS. The command executes successfully, however when I check the metadata, the min and max values are both 0, and the map shows one singular color throughout the region. How do I fix this issue so that the distances are accurately represented? The raster that I'm trying to derive distances from was rasterized in ArcGIS Pro from TIGER shapefiles for PriSec Roads.

I've tried re-importing the raster using r.in.gdal, and tried r.grow.distance again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computational region needs to match the road raster, run `g.region raster=roads` in command console or display the raster and right click at the layer and look for *Set computational region to match the raster*.

Also make sure areas other than roads are represented as no data.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. My raster file had values ranging from 0 to 2, there were no null values, which is why every cell had a value of 0 when running the command.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer, I believe the second part answers your question.

Comment: Just did! Sorry I'm a new user, I didn't know that was a feature.